# How can I convert rows to column using VBA or Python?

Tags: python, vba, database, pivot

[image: Excel Example]

I need to convert the table at the top, which consists of rows for 1 single flight.
I have no idea where to start to create a VBA or Python script to transpose it to get the format like the graph at the bottom, any ideas?
I am still very new to coding and data manipulation and appreciate your help.

Comment: Describe your input and output parameters data structures and we can show you how to transform from one to another.  The image above is helpful, but they are not (yet) actual data structures in either VBA or Python.  Is this an Excel worksheet that you want to take the top cells and output the bottom cells?

Comment: Depending on where you are going to use your single row you can use the filters button in excel and filter to show only 1 data point. You could also use a separate sheet and use a vlookup or xlookup to retrieve and assemble rows of data for your purposes.

Comment: Good evening gents, thank you for replying.
I need to clean the data to parse into Tableau desktop. However, column "H" represent milestones in a process, aircraft left stand, push back tug left stand etc. But Tableau needs to recognise those types as dimensions. Currently, Tableau will recognise "Type" as a dimension and just have all the milestones as values. I need all the types as dimensions with the timestamp. I apologise if its confusing. Im familiar with Python and VBA, but I simply dont know how to approach this problem. Could I group by ID and then flight, as they're are consistent.

Comment: I know how to do what you are asking in terms of program logic, and I know VBA, Excel, the Excel data model and API and how this could be done from/to Excel ranges.  I do not know Tableau or it's interfaces and your response does not tell me what data structures and data types are to be used for input and output.

Comment: @Dean It is the enumeration of the distinct input Types (in column H) into separate accumulated columns in the output that is the tricky part here.  If there is some fixed master list of these, that would not be too hard.  But, I assume that list is supposed to be existential (i.e., dynamically based on the distinct Type-values that are actually present in the input) in which case it quite a bit harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pandas `pivot_table` to do the above work.

Here is an example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_excel

df = read_excel(<your_file.xlsx>)
altered_df=df.pivot_table(values=['Timestamp'],columns=['Type'], index=[<rest_of_your_columns_that_you_want_to_retain>])

DataFrame(altered_df.to_records())
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time reply, I really appreciate it.
I will give this a shot

Answer (score 0):

To everyone that took the time to read and respond to my issue, thank you.
I managed to figure out a way with VBA, using the following code. Some manipulation had to be made before running the code, such as adjusting headers etc.

```
Dim i As Integer 'Import row
Dim k As Integer 'Pivot row
Dim m As Integer 'Pivot column
Dim Timestamp As Date

i = 2
k = 1

Do Until Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = ""
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) <> Sheet1.Cells(i - 1, 3) Then
        k = k + 1
        Sheet2.Cells(k, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
        Sheet2.Cells(k, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
        Sheet2.Cells(k, 4) = "LGW"
        Sheet2.Cells(k, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
        Sheet2.Cells(k, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7)
    End If
    m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Cells(i, 8), Sheet2.Rows(1), 0)
    If Sheet2.Cells(k, 1) = "" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(k, 1) = DateSerial(Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 4), Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 6, 2), Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 9, 2))
    End If
    Sheet2.Cells(k, m) = DateSerial(Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 4), Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 6, 2), Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 9, 2)) + (Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 12, 2) / 24) + (Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 15, 2) / 1440) + (Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 18, 2) / 86400)
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```